# Measure the Delta of ASP.NET performance

Tags: asp.net

My project will add a HttpModule to legacy system to do some filtering action. The system administrators hope us to provide the stastics Delta about CPU, the # of current users being serviced, etc.

Does anybody can suggest tools or strategy to go about this kind of simulation?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create some custom performance counters to represent the quantities/rates you want to measure:

- [How to: Create Custom Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e3s61wf.aspx)
- [How To: Use Custom Performance Counters from ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979204.aspx)

Your system admins will be able to use Perfmon.exe (a standard tool they should be familiar with) to view your custom counters.

Another option is to use System.Diagnostics or Log4Net; for example:

- [Monitor Your Apps with System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163582.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use [Performance Counters for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx); Admins could access them through Performance Monitor